# Conversion of Expression in Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, expression, automapper

I am working on an application in which I am communicating to Database via Generic Repository and UnitOfWork. In my service layer I have to convert my ViewModel to actual database model,with the help of Automapper, in order to get data from database. All is going well but I am having issue when want to convert expression by Automapper. It is converted, but when in GenericRepository this method executes

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetWithInclude(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate, params string[] include)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = this.DbSet;
            query = include.Aggregate(query, (current, inc) => current.Include(inc));
            var result= query.Where(predicate).ToList();
            return query.Where(predicate);
        }
```

on this statement:

```
var result= query.Where(predicate).ToList();
```

it gives this error.

System.ArgumentException: 'ParameterExpression of type 'BusinessEntities.ProductEntity' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'DataModel.Data.tblProduct''

here is debug view after conversion
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[DataModel.Data.tblProduct,System.Boolean]>(BusinessEntities.ProductEntity $x) { $x.Price > (System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal])((System.Decimal)0)
}

this is my mapping code

```
MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>cfg.CreateMap<Expression<Func<ProductEntity, bool>> , Expression<Func<tblProduct, bool>>> ());
IMapper _Mapper = _config.CreateMapper();
var exp = _Mapper.Map<Expression<Func<tblProduct, bool>>>(query);
```

How can I change delegate parameter to type tblProduct.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Asif Aziz.

I tried ExpressionVisitor

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu the repository you mentioned is developed in .net standard 2.1. it support automapper 12.0. In my case I am using .net framework 4.8.1 it does not support auto mapper 12.0.

Comment: You have to choose an older version then. One that works with AM 10.1.1.